# How to set 'condition' using a condition stored in a property?

Tags: msbuild, conditional-statements

I have a condition such as 'a==1' stored in property $(c) and I wanna used it as the condition for task Message like below code:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <aa>1>2</aa>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="t">
    <Message Text="122333" Condition="$(aa)" />
  </Target>
```

Error was raised!
So, how can I do it? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use property values for evaluating conditions.  Here is an example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <aa>1</aa>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Some text" Condition=" $(aa) &lt; 2 " />
</Target>
```

Note that:

- Property values are strings, you must evaluate the condition in the Condition attribute.  See [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) on evaluating conditions.
- You must escape XML characters (replace `<` with `&lt;` )

Comment: I agree with you. 
In addition to note, I put "1 &lt; 2" into property aa and see that the condition doesn't work!
So what can we do to have the codition stored in a property? 

I try to escape &lt; one more time, i.e. "1 %26lt%3B 2" is put into aa, but it is not accepted either. I give up :(