# Trick to run different pre/post build events when building with MSBuild or from Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, command-line, msbuild, ide

Don't ask me why, but does anyone know any trick to put in the pre/post build event command that will run different commands if the project is being built from command line with MSBuild or from inside the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731502/in-msbuild-is-it-possible-to-determine-if-im-running-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Darien Pardinas, any update for this question? Could you get any useful info from the answer and the comment?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to define build targets that are conditioned on the `$(BuildingInVisualStudio)` property that [visual studio sets to `true` when buildinging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468(en-us).aspx#Anchor_6).

```
<Target Name="SpecialPreBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(BuildingInVisualStudio)' != 'true'">
  <Exec Command="some-command.exe --magic" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="foo.txt" DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\bar" />
</Target>

<Target Name="SpecialPostBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(BuildingInVisualStudio)' != 'true'">
  <Exec Command="some-other-command.exe --magic" />
</Target>
```

If you want to skip these targets in other IDEs / editors as well, you could introduce a custom property as well and change the `Condition` attributes above to

```
Condition="'$(PerformSpecialLogic)' == 'true'"
```

That way no "default" builds will execute these targets and you could build with the following arguments in your build script / CI definition:

```
msbuild /p:PerformSpecialLogic=true
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use the existing `$(BuildingInVisualStudio)` property?

Comment: I've seen that before but couldn't find good (/recent) documentation on that to make sure it is "public". @stijn Do you know any? Don't want to add it without source..

Comment: I'm also not sure if R#'s build calls / Rider / VS/Mac / OmniSharp (VSCode) also set this property. At least I couldn't find it in the OmniSharp source.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468(en-us).aspx. No idea if other environments set it, and while it's not bad you want to take them into account, the OP doesn't ask about them so it might not matter for him.

Comment: @stijn do you want to add another answer? i'd delete this one afterwards.

Comment: No need for that. Your answer with the custom property is also viable, and I'd just be duplicating code like yours and changing a single property name. Just edit your answer, mentioning that when using VS one can swap PerformSpecialLogic with the built-in BuildingInVisualStudio property. And add the link as well. Then the answer is complete, seems easier for future visitors.

Comment: @MartinUllrich This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2017 mentions `$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)`, while your answer mentions `$(BuildingInVisualStudio)`. Are those two the same, and if yes, why the latter is not documented? Thanks.